# Is there any difference between medical and cleaning ozone?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, terminology

What are the main differences between medical ozone (auto-hemotherapy, …) and cleaning ozone (for example, the kitchen cleaning devices for vegetables and food). I noticed that they can produce a lower amount of ozone per hour while the medical ones have bigger amount of production.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: I see as the only difference the ozone concentration and the gas mixture purpose. The ozone itself is the same, there is no medical nor cleaning ozone. Breathing ozone containing gas is harmful. It is a potent gas initiating the SO2 imission damage of spruce trees, and is the key component of the oxidative smog of the Los Angeles type, that can cause defoliation of trees.

Answer (score 4):

“Medical ozone” is a mixture of 0.05 to 5 vol% of ozone produced from medically pure oxygen (usually via silent electrical discharge) and 99.95 to 95 vol% of oxygen.
Using air for medical-grade ozone production is strictly forbidden due to formation of hazardous nitrogen oxides $\ce{NO_x}.$
Note that [ozone therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_therapy) is still considered an alternative medicine.

Ozone used for cleaning doesn't have such constrains and its concentration and production method vastly depends on application area and regulatory standards therein.
For example, for water treatment Russian federal standards prescribe the ozone concentration in the ozone-air mixture from 15 to 22 mg/l based on the required efficiency and level of pollution of the water source, and average contact time of 5 to 15 min.
Prolonged exposure or increased ozone concentration during water treatment may lead to unwanted effects such as problems with coagulation and extensive phenols formation.